# CakePHP authentication plugin returns empty identity object

Tags: authentication, cakephp, jwt, cakephp-3.0

I'm using CakePHP 3.5.14 and the [official CakePHP authentication plugin](https://github.com/cakephp/authentication) v1.0.0-rc4 with JWT authentication. The authentication itself (generating and evaluating tokens) works, but trying to get the identity of the token holder returns an empty object. 
I have my `User` model ([which is the default model for the ORM resolver](https://github.com/cakephp/authentication/blob/master/docs/Identifiers.md#orm-resolver)) set up and running, there is nothing special about the `users` table, it has the usual columns `id`, `username`, `password`, `email`. `cakephp/orm` has been required by composer.

This is the content of the JWT payload:

```
{
  "sub": 9,
  "aud": "http://example.com"
}
```

This is the code of the controller function:

```
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $result = $this->Authentication->getResult();
    if ($result->isValid()) {  //evaluates true
        $user = $this->Authentication->getIdentity();
        $response = $user;
    } else {
        $response = array("error" => "You are not authorized.");
    }

    $json = json_encode($response);  //becomes {}
    $this->response->type('json');
    $this->response->body($json);
    return $this->response;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An empty JSON representation doesn't necessarily mean that the object is "empty", but only that its JSON representation is.

The API around identities has changed quite a bit lately, `\Authentication\Controller\Component\AuthenticationComponent::getIdentity()` returns `\Authentication\IdentityInterface`, which doesn't contain JSON serialization capabilities, and the available `IdentityInterface` implementation doesn't store data in public properties, so its JSON representation will always be empty.

If you want to access the retrieved data, which for the ORM resolver should be an entity (note that the contract however defines `\ArrayAccess|array`, so be sure to implement a check if you expect an entity), then invoke `\Authentication\IdentityInterface::getOriginalData()`:

```
$identity = $this->Authentication->getIdentity();
$user = $identity->getOriginalData();
```

See also

- **[Authentication Cookbook > The Identity Object](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/1/en/identity-object.html)**

Comment: Please fix link for **Authentication Docs > The Identity Object**